# php/mysql/ajax: google style search with suggestions

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have an ajax script that searches database tables for expressions similar to google search.  The SELECT statement just uses LIKE and finds matches in the relevant fields. It worked fine at first but as content has grown, it is giving way too many matches for most search strings.

For example, if you search for att, you get att but also attention, attaboy, buratta etc.

Good search engines such as Google seem to have an intermediate table of suggestions that have been vetted by others.  Rather than search the data directly, they seem to search the approved phrases such as AT&T and succeed in narrowing the number of results.  Has anyone coded something like this and suggest the right dbase schema and query to get relevant results.

Right now I am searching table of say names directly with something like

```
$sql = "SELECT lastname from people WHERE lastname LIKE '%$searchstring%'";
```

I imagine besides people I should create some intermediate table along the lines of

people

```
id|firstname|lastname|description
```

niceterms

```
id|niceterm|peopleid
```

Then the query could be:

```
$sql = "SELECT p.lastname,p.peopleid, n.niceterm, n.peopleid,
FROM `people` p
LEFT JOIN `niceterms` n
on p.id = n.peopleid
WHERE niceterm LIKE '%$searchterm%'";
```

..so when you type something in the search box, you get nice search terms that will yield better results.

But how do I populate the niceterms table.  Is this the right approach?  I'm not trying to create a whole backweb or pagerank.  Just want to narrow search results so they are relevant.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at FULLTEXT search in Mysql. It allowes you to create powerfull query's based on relevance. You can for example create a BOOLEAN search which allowes you to create a scorerow in your result. The score will be based on rules like does the text start with a karakter combination (yes? +2, no but it does contain the combination: +1)

The below code is just another column and it has 3 rules in it:

- Does the `p1`.`name` field contain Bl or rock? if yes -> add score
- Does the  `p1`.`name` field start with either Bl or rock? if yes -> add score
- IS the `p1`.`name` equal to Bl rock? if yes -> add score

  MATCH `p1`.`name` AGAINST('>Bl* >rock* >((+Bl*) (+rock*)) >("Bl rock")' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS `match`

Now just order by `match` and it will show you the most relevant searches. You can also combine the order by with multiple statements and add a limit like below:

Orders by most recent date, highest match and then orders the matches that have the same score by their character length

```
ORDER BY `date` DESC, `match` DESC, LENGTH(`p1`.`name`) ASC
```

Keep in mind that the above code somehow creates a relevant result based on common cases. Copying Google will be imposible since their algorithms for optimal results / speed are incredible.

If FULLTEXT search is a step to much, try to make a tag system. Tagging content with unique tag combinations will also result in a more reliable search result

Comment: So you would improve the results with the part of the statement that creates the match column?

Comment: Yup. Based on relevance When you type in Rock, the first result will be Rock and then Rockability and then Hardrock for example